# Managing different customer variants in yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

We have successfully set up Yocto for our self-developed hardware.
For this hardware, different customer images are to be managed, which only differ in the application programmes used.
The hardware is the same for all projects.
The software is distributed both as image and ipk packages.
Our goal is to make customized packages available for download in their own customized directory.

Our approach is to create a separate Yocto layer for each customer project. This layer extends the image specification, among other things.

The customized layer is entered in bblayers.conf. In this way, we are able to create customized images of the form:
`<base-imagename>-<customer-variant>`

Unfortunately, I don't know of an automated way to sort the ipk packages in the `./build/deploy/ipk`  directory so that they are in a custom folder.
Attempts with the variable PACKAGE_ARCH were promising. However, this led to other errors:
`No manifest generated from <recipe>.bb`

Searching the internet for a basic procedure in this case unfortunately led to no result.

Therefore, I would like to ask here for the best procedure to manage different client projects in yocto?

Comment: What if you would have separate `build` folders for the different variants, while having common downloads folder and shared state cache?